# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value Swift nil

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLu1s.png)

I try to search this issue in SOW,
comment part is not avaiable now,my Xcode is 7.1 and iOS 9.0 Simulator
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

how to solve this issue?
thank you

I removed as! ,but xcode suggest me append as.......

`var cell:UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId)! as  UITableViewCell`

Comment: remove the `! as UITableViewCell`

Comment: This is probably the most common issue the new Swift developers can have, there are hundreds of answers on SO, you can find a very detailed explanation at some of them or at every Swift cookbook. What interests me is the part "comment part is not available now", could you elaborate ?

Answer (score 0):

Way too much code.

```
let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Default, reuseIdentifier: cellId)
```

It won't be nil unless your tableview's reuseIdentifier isn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
let cell = tableView1.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellId, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
```

That means that the cell with the correct ID will be placed into the correct space on the `UITableView`. Also, I think that having `tableView` at the front might have caused the error, so I changed it to `tableView1`.